# Capacitor 3 & Facebook Android SDK, how to get request code in ActivityCallback method

Tags: android, angular, facebook, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Currently I'm creating my own Facebook login plugin using Capacitor 3 and Facebook Android SDK. I'm stuck on `onActivityResult` facebook method where I need to pass activity request code. How to get this code?

```
@CapacitorPlugin(
        name = "FacebookLoginSdk",
        permissions = {
                @Permission(
                        alias = "internet",
                        strings = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                )
        }
)
public class FacebookLoginSdkPlugin extends Plugin {

    ...
    @PluginMethod
    public void login(PluginCall call) {
        callbackId = call.getCallbackId();
        bridge.saveCall(call);

        if (getPermissionState("internet") != PermissionState.GRANTED) {
            requestPermissionForAlias("internet", call, "internetPermsCallback");
        } else {
            logInWithReadPermissions(call);
        }
    }

    @PermissionCallback
    private void internetPermsCallback(PluginCall call) {
        if (getPermissionState("internet") == PermissionState.GRANTED) {
            logInWithReadPermissions(call);
        } else {
            call.reject("Permission is required");
        }
    }

    private void logInWithReadPermissions(PluginCall call) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();

        startActivityForResult(call, intent, "loginResultCallback");
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(activity, Arrays.asList(facebookPermissions));
    }

    @ActivityCallback
    private void loginResultCallback(PluginCall call, ActivityResult result) {
        if (call == null) {
            return;
        }
        int resultCode = result.getResultCode();
        Intent data = result.getData();

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(???REQUEST_CODE???, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Property what I was looking for is FACEBOOK_SDK_REQUEST_CODE_OFFSET